# Responsive navbar in Blueprint?

Tags: blueprintjs

I am trying to use Blueprint in my new project instead of Bootstrap.

How can I make a responsive navbar in Blueprint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blueprint is designed for desktop-only apps so we do not support responsive-ness out of the box. That said, you can easily [pin a navbar to the top of the viewport](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/v1/#core/components/navbar.fixed-to-viewport-top), and a small amount of custom styles should get you the rest of the way.